# Refer from programmatically created JSF-code to other element for rerendering

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using Apache MyFaces lib to create JSF Tags, for example HtmlAjaxCommandLink. There is a method setReRender(parameter) to identify the corresponding element, which should get updated. In my HTML-source the corresponding anchor has an id-attribute with the value 'subformContainer_7_facesMessagesContainer'.

What do I have to set as a parameter? Thanks in advance.

Currently the area (a t:div) is not rerendered at all. To evaluate if the area is rerendered I am using a randomNumberString, so I should recognize if the value changes.

```
String rrString = "subformContainer_7_facesMessagesContainer";System.out.println("DEBUG rrString : " + rrString);
treeResizeButton.setReRender(rrString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tell JSF to re-render a component in the current Ajax request, you can use the API for [PartialViewContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html):

```
PartialViewContext partialViewCtx = FacesContext.getInstance().getPartialViewContext();
partialViewCtx.getRenderIds().add("putYourClientIdHere")
```

Or, if you use the OmniFaces library, you can simply use [Ajax#update](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Ajax.html#update%28java.lang.String...%29).